# Sending SMS in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sms

I've got an iPhone 5S and I send a lots of SMS and my fingers feel like they're about to fall off.

Is it possible to send SMS from my Ubuntu system, and recieving sms on my system?

Comment: your mobile operator may provide a web-interface to send SMS. Then there is something like twilio.

Comment: Twilio? And my operator had it but removed it...

Comment: Really, isn`t there anyone that can help me out?